# How to pass two different arguments in a single function in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, foreign-keys

Python newbie here, I am trying to create a web-app where shippers can post their truck-loads on sale and accept bids from transporters, and the transporters can post their bids on loads.

I have a list view function in my views.py, where a shipper can see all the bids posted by different suppliers, and then he can 'assign' one supplier for that post-load.

[image: loads]

For that I created this function which takes 2 arguments : the quiz.id (which is the unique primary key of the post-load) and the supplier's ID.

urls.py

```
 path('confirm/<int:pk>/', teachers.ConfirmRFQ, name='ConfirmRFQ'),
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def ConfirmRFQ (request, pk,bi):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
    bid = Bid.objects.get(pk=bi)
    quiz.status = 'Assigned'
    bid.confirmed = 'Assigned'
    quiz.save()
    bid.save()

    return redirect('teachers:quiz_change_list')
```

The function call in template:

```
 <a href="{% url 'teachers:ConfirmRFQ' quiz.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Assign</a>
```

Is there something wrong here ? Can I not pass two arguments as such ? Because I keep getting the

> NoReverseMatch at /teachers/quiz/13/results/
>
> Reverse for 'ConfirmRFQ' with arguments '(13, 33)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['teachers/confirm/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

error.

Not sure if model is necassary here, but here it is:

models.py

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    bid_status_choices = (('Active', 'Active'), ('Assigned', 'Assigned'), ('Dispatched', 'Dispatched'), ('Delayed', 'Delayed'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'))
    mtypes =(('Fragile','Fragile'),('Non-Fragile','Non-Fragile'))

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes')
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=0)
    total_trucks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    material_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=0, choices=mtypes)
    scheduled_date = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=0)
    offered_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Active', choices=bid_status_choices)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name

class Bid(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    text = models.CharField('Answer', max_length=255)
    bid_amount = models.CharField('bid_amount', max_length=255,default=0)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField('Correct answer', default=False)
    bid_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: you need to extend the URL pattern so that it takes `bi` as an argument - just as you already have done with `pk`. Is there some reason you can't do this? (I'm not entirely sure how your app works, but you will likely need some authentication to stop users being able to access things that they shouldn't be able to see/do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend your path with an aribitrary number of parameters, here for example the pattern should probably look like:

```
path('confirm/<int:pk>/<int:bi>', teachers.ConfirmRFQ, name='ConfirmRFQ'),
```

So the view requires *two* parameters here: `pk` and `bi`.

In your template for example, you can then retrieve the URL by passing two parameters like:

```
{% url 'teachers:ConfirmRFQ' pk=quiz.pk bi=mybid.pk %}
```

Note however that updating entities is typically *not* done through a GET request (since a GET request should not have any side-effects), but through a POST request.